# Is there a one-word for an act of proactively introducing oneself?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, paraphrasing

I work for a technology company, and we are associating with another company. So this guy from the other company wrote me an email introducing himself and offering to help me out with anything I needed when I am working with their stuff.

I want to thank him, so I started replying like this:

> Dear Mr. X,
>
> Thank you for ... <what do I put here?>

I want to say: *for introducing yourself and offering to help me out*, blah blah. But then that will be just a copy of what he offered to do in his mail, so I wanted to check if there is some other word/paraphrasing I could use to that effect?

Comment: Thank you so much for the introduction and kind offer of help.

Comment: hmm..I guess thats good enough, Perhaps I was searching for a word to encapsulate the spirit of his offering, however it might sound a bit....pompous maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I think I would start by saying how grateful you are that there is someone willing to stop what they are doing and help.

"Good day Mr. X":
I am very grateful that you stepped up to help me in my learning curve. Indeed, I may call on you in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

*Networking* is the word I would use.

> **Networking** *verb, gerund, or present partciple*. Interact with other people to exchange information and develop contacts, especially to further one's career.

- [Google (Source)](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=define%20networking)

> Dear Mr. X,
>
> Thank you for networking with me at the conference earlier......

I would probably rephrase that first sentence and say:

*Dear Mr. X,*

*It was a pleasure networking with you at the conference earlier...*

Answer (score 1):

In my correspondence I use the phrase "*reaching out*" for this case.

> Dear Mr. X,
>
> Thank you for reaching out on LinkedIn. As it happens, I actually am interested in...

I settled on that phrase because it implies that the gratitude I'm offering is for an above and beyond effort on the part of the other person to seek me out and contact me; that they're reaching out from their easy circle of acquaintances to do so.

I find the physical simile handily illustrates my appreciation of the degree of effort involved.

Answer (score 0):

**make someone's acquaintance:** *(v.)* to come into social contact with someone

> I'm very much obliged to have made your acquaintance.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I'd use the word [greeting](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=greeting&use1828=on) in the noun form in the sense of "salutation at meeting."

"Thank you for the kind greeting and offering to help me out [et cetera]"

Speaking of which, in order to understand that you'll need the definition of [Salutation](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=Salutation&use1828=on), which is a bit less common now but still recognizable enough to be suitable:

> n. The act of saluting; a greeting; the act of paying respect or reverence by the customary words or actions; as in inquiring of persons their welfare, expressing to them kind wishes, bowing, &c. [Luke 1:29](http://thekingsbible.com/bibletext.aspx?bibleid=42001029); [Mark 12:38](http://thekingsbible.com/bibletext.aspx?bibleid=41012038) [Holy Bible verses]
>
> In all public meetings and private addresses, use the forms of salutation, reverence and decency usual among the most sober people.

It basically refers to the proper manners of introduction or day to day meetings.

"Thank you for the salutation, [et cetera]"

Referenced definitions are from [Noah Webster's 1828 American Dictionary of the English Language.](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/)